# What filesystem should be used with an external hard disk larger than 8TB on windows 10 for use with transparent compression?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs

I have a 40TiB external storage array connected via USB and I need to format it for use with Windows 10.
The problem i see is that NTFS only supports these large volumes with sectors larger than 4096B which is a limit i dont want to exceed, because NTFS compression does not work beyond it.

Are there filesystems with transparent compression available for Windows 10, that support 40TiB volumes?

Comment: But everything else also does not have NTFS compression…?

Comment: I was about to comment the same thing. It sounds like you have already done some research on different file formats. It is highly unlikely that you will get any better answers here. You will have to choose one that is supported by Windows 10, and can handle large partitions. There are likely to be pros and cons, but you haven't given enough information about what the purpose of this drive is/how often you will access these files/whether it needs to be readable on other devices

Comment: Ok do you have any recommendation? its not really about the best fit at this point, it just seems to me like you can not get transparent compression at all with this large a volume which seems very strange to me. I checked FAT32, exFat, NTFS, HFS, HFS+ and ReFS

Comment: Why not just create three individual volumes then and keep the 4 KB clusters? Why not instead look at deduplication rather than transparent compression? It's not really that surprising as storage is cheap and especially transparent compression on large files is going to be very expensive.

Comment: You might want to ask such a question over at Serverfault or another community

Comment: @user134450 you can't use HFS and HFS+ on Windows, and both are far worse than NTFS. If installing a driver is OK then you can use [Btrfs](https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs) or [ZFS](https://github.com/openzfsonwindows/ZFSin)

Comment: @phuclv thank you! Thats the piece of information i needed rechecked. It seems so weird to me that windows does not support this out of the box. But i guess filesystems are not something you change overnight.

Comment: @user134450 yes, you typically need years of development to make sure that a file system is stable enough to not blow up users' data. APFS is an exception, probably because HFS+ was so bad and Apple has to put lots of resources into bringing APFS to life ASAP. I don't know what's wrong with ReFS, but it's working in Windows Server so I suppose it should be quite stable for use as of now, I think you can use it